# Event listener on different object

Tags: javascript

What is a better way to write this code, i feel like i should be able to reference the target in a less hard coded way. is it ok to add the actual object to the  variable instead, and if so, how do i test/verify where the event is added?

```
var o="window"; // or "document" or "body" or maybe some at the moment unknown elements id

if(o=="window"){
    window.addEventListener();
} 
else if(o=="document"){
    window.document.addEventListener();
}
else if(o=="body"){
    window.document.body.addEventListener();
}
```

Comment: Yes, just put the object in the variable. `var o = document.body;`

Comment: And then `o.addEventListener(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that

```js
const elementX =
    { 'window'   : window
    , 'document' : window.document
    , 'body'     : window.document.body
    }

var o="window";

elementX[o].addEventListener( ... );
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add the object to the variable instead. That way your code just looks like this:

```
function addEventHandler(dom_object) {
    if (dom_object) domobject.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var target = (e || window.event).target
        switch (target) {
            case: window:
            case: document:
            case: document.body:
            //....
        }
    });
}

addEventHandler(window)
addEventHandler(document)
addEventHandler(document.body)
```

I am not sure I understood you last question but you can check the object that triggered the event with event.target. See above code.